# Combobox Value Loading Problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mysql

Using C# & MySQL

When i select a particular value from the combobox then i clicked the button, the corresponding value should display in the other textbox

code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd2 = new OdbcCommand("Select name from users where username = '" + combobox1.Text  + "' ", con);
        dr1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            textbox1.Text = dr1.GetString(0);

        }
        dr1.Close();

    }
```

The Above Code is working, but nothing displaying in Textbox1, there is the problem only in the query, I changed the query like  `Select name from users where username = '005'`
Output is displaying in the textbox1, but when i used combobox value it is not displaying.

I also tried:

```
combobox1.text, combobox1.selectedvalue, combobox1.selecteditem, combobox1.selectedindex
```

Combobox Filling Code

```
cmd2 = new OdbcCommand("Select username from users, con);
        ada2 = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd2);
        ada2.Fill(data2);
        combobox1.DataValueField = "username";
        combobox1.DataSource = data2;
```

combobox1.DataBind();

Username values like 201, 202, 203....,

Why is the query executing while using the combobox value....

Need Query Help

Comment: You have a SQL Injection hole.

Comment: What's the value of the combobox?

Comment: Not really related to your problem but I suggest you take a look at Sql command parameters. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx 

For future reference ;)

Comment: You should use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the `cmd2 = ...` line, run it, push the button, and then open the “Watch” window to find out what value `combobox1.Text` has.

Comment: if there's numbers try appending ToString() to the end? I dunno if that'd help :? 

EDIT: nevermind...using Text should return a string x__x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using winform controls, please use below code

```
comboBox1.DataSource = list;
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
```

to get value from combobox use comboBox1.SelectedValue[It will return object type]

Answer (score 2):

`comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].Text` should give you what you want.

---

wrap your combo box's filling code in

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack) {}
```

It should be filled only when the page is loaded the first time and not on subsequent postbacks otherwise it will reset the binding everytime the page is posted back.

Comment: make sure that value of SelectedIndex is >= 0 to avoid out of index exceptions.

Comment: Have you set you `DrowDownList`'s `AutoPostBack` property to `True`?

Comment: If i used the AutoPostBack = true, the combobox value displaying from the first value, it is not displaying a selected value.....

Comment: When i clicked the Button, the combobox value is displaying from the first value, it is not displaying a selected value, what is the problem in my webpage....

Comment: have you tried using both `comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].Text` and `comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].Value`?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `combobox1.SelectedItem.Text` for the desired result.